# hhvm > Postgres works on CLI, not via NGINX

Tags: postgresql, nginx, hhvm

I am running hhvm 3.2.0 and am trying to get the Postgres part set up. We have the extension loaded, and it works when running on the CLI, but when I run via NGINX through the browser there is nothing, no output, no lines in any logs (HHVM / NGINX / System)

The pre-requisite libpq is installed and updated.

My hunch is that its an issue with the fastCGI, but Wordpress runs fine, so I am now lost.

Can anyone point me in a direction to find out what is wrong please? Thanks in advance!

Here is what I have:

```
root@ip-172-31-2-84:~# php -v
HipHop VM 3.2.0 (rel)
Compiler: tags/HHVM-3.2.0-0-g01228273b8cf709aacbd3df1c51b1e690ecebac8
Repo schema: c52ba40f4a246d35a88f1dfc1daf959851ced8aa
```

/etc/hhvm/config.hdf:

```
DynamicExtensionPath = /data/config/etc/hhvm/extensions
DynamicExtensions {
    * = pgsql.so
}
```

conf.d/hhvm.conf :

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

fastcgi_params:

```
fastcgi_param   PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;

fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

fastcgi_param   HTTPS                   $https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
```

pgsql.so from https://github.com/PocketRent/hhvm-pgsql/tree/releases/3.2.0/ubuntu/trusty

PHP file to test it all: (k.hh)

```
if (extension_loaded('pgsql')) {

echo "hello pgsql";
try{
   $db = pg_connect( "host=xxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=production user=dbu password=xxxxx" );
   var_dump($db);
}
   catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }
}else{
   echo "no pgsql";
}
```

Running from the CLI:

```
root@ip-172-31-2-84:~# hhvm /var/www/medic52.com/www/k.hh
hello pgsqlresource(4) of type (pgsql connection)
```

Equivalent on the web: 
http://www.medic52.com/k.hh

The NGINX access.log confirms a server error:

`17.124.20.86 - - [12/Aug/2014:05:54:28 +0000] "GET /k.hh HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36" "-"`

Comment: 404, file not found?

Comment: We have since abandoned HHVM as no answer was forthcoming, and due to commercial reasons neede to not spend time on it, or have the issues that HHVM still has.